# How to perform find() and compare values in ionic storage?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-storage

I am using `'@ionic/storage'` in my app, I am storing values in it. However, I want to perform some check/find on those values. I have figured out how to perform it on array (nameData), but dont know how to find element in ionic/storage.

This function returns true if the param passed matches with the key:value in nameData array.

```
nameCheck(nameData: Name) {
    return this.nameData.find((nameEl: Name) => {
        return nameEl.name == nameData.name;
    })
}
```

How can I perform similar kind of function using `'@ionic/Storage'`?

```
nameCheck(nameData: Name) {
    return this.storage.get('nameData').then(res => { return res });
}
```

P.S Storage key nameData contains copy of nameData array. nameCheck() should return boolean value.

Comment: Check out [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-2-storage-get-all-stored-keys-foreach-method/71348) link. this.storage.forEach should work for you!

Comment: @Philip thanks, but I am storing array of objects into storage.